# GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED on remote socket closure

Tags: winsock, getlasterror, io-completion-ports

I am writing a small server-client-stuff using an I/O-Completion Port.

I get the server and client connected successfully via AcceptEx over my completion port.
After the client has connected the client socket is associated with the completion port and an overlapped call to WSARecv on that socket is invoked.

Everything works just fine, until I close the client test program.
`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError` returns

> ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED

, which makes sense to me (after I read the description on the MSDN).

But my problem is, that I thought the call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` would return me a packet indicating the failure due to closure of the socket, because `WSARecv` would return the apropriate return value.
Since this is not the case I don´t know which clients´ socket caused the error and cant act the way i need to (freeing structures , cleanup for this particular connection, etc)...

Any suggestion on how to solve this, Or hints?

Thanks:)

EDIT: http://codepad.org/WeYINasO <- the code responsible... the "error" occures at the first functions beginning of the while-loop (the call to `GetCompletionStatus()` which is only a wrapper for GetQueuedCompletionStatus() working fine in other cases) [Did post it there, because it looks shitty & messy in here]

Comment: Can you show us some code, please?

Comment: which part do you need? if(GetQueuedCompletionStatus() == FALSE) or the GetLastError-Part? hahahaha ;)...

Nah... to be honest... which part? ... There is no sense in posting it all from my point of view, because it´s a therory-thing as far as i see

Comment: You're making a big assumption there. Do you want help or not?

Comment: yes... but my question still is: which part(s) do you need to fully understand it? it wouldnt make sense to post the creation of listenen socket etc... I just dont want to mess the OP up with posting too much irrelevant stuff

Comment: added the codepad-link to the parts of the code, i think that are responsible for this (at least the error occures there)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling WSAGetLastError() from an IOCP thread return incorrect result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925003/calling-wsagetlasterror-from-an-iocp-thread-return-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the scenarios that you need to watch for when calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`:

- **`GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns `TRUE`:** A successful completion packet has been received, all the out parameters have been populated.
- **`GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns `FALSE`, `lpOverlapped == NULL`:** No packet was dequeued. The other out parameters contain indeterminate values.
- **`GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns `FALSE`, `lpOverlapped != NULL`:** The function has dequeued a failed completion packet. The error code is available via `GetLastError`.

To answer your question, when `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns `FALSE` and `lpOverlapped != NULL`, there was a failed I/O completion. It's the value of `lpOverlapped` that you need to be concerned about.

Comment: I encounter the last option.
I guess I should read the socket out through the extended overlapped structure and close it.

Thank you :)

Comment: I have a question plz. If `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns `FALSE`, `lpOverlapped != NULL`, is there one and only one packet has dequeued and this packet is faild? Only one?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I found this page while fruitlessly googling for details about `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED`.  It is an error which I get while doing an overlapped `Readfile()`.

After some debugging it turned out that the problem was caused by a program which was writing to a socket but forgetting to call `closesocket()` before using `ExitProcess()` (due to garbage collection issues).  Calling `CloseHandle()` did not prevent the error, nor did adding `WSACleanup()` before `ExitProcess()`.  However, adding a short sleep before the client exited did prevent the error.  Maybe avoiding `ExitProcess()` would have prevented the problem also.

So I suspect your problem is caused by the program exiting without closing down the socket properly.

I don't think this would be an issue on Unix where sockets are just ordinary file descriptors.