# Calling WSAGetLastError() from an IOCP thread return incorrect result

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

I have called `WSARecv()` which returned `WSA_IO_PENDING`. I have then sent an `RST` packet from the other end. The `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` function which exists in another thread has returned `FALSE` as expected, but when I called `WSAGetLastError()` I got `64` instead of `WSAECONNRESET`.

So why `WSAGetLastError()` did not return `WSAECONNRESET`?

---

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that when I call `WSAGetLastError()` directly after a failing `WSARecv()` (because of an `RST` packet being received), the error code returned is `WSAECONNRESET` and not `64`.

So it looks like the error code returned depends on whether `WSARecv()` has failed directly after calling it, or has failed later when retrieving a completion packet.

Comment: 64 is `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED`. That is just the way it works.  You will have to deal with it.  In my experience using WinSock IOCP, it will usually report `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED` and not `WSAECONNRESET`, so just handle both errors as if they were the same.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Will all error codes returned by `WSAGetLastError()` inside of an IOCP thread be `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED` or just `WSAECONNRESET`?

Comment: Not all errors, but I do not know which ones specifically map to `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED`. I always treat it as an unexpected disconnect.  Does it really matter if it was caused by a `RST` or not?  It is not a graceful disconnect one way or the other.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau In my case it does not matter, however knowing the reason for disconnection could matter in other cases.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a generic issue with IOCP, you are making a low-level call to the TCP/IP driver stack.  Which, as all drivers do in Windows, report failure with NTSTATUS error codes.  The expected error here is STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET.

These native error codes need to be translated to a winapi error code.  This translation is normally *context-sensitive*, it depends on what winapi library issued the driver command.  In other words, you can only ever get a WSAECONNRESET error back if it was the Winsock library that did the translation.  But that's not what happened in your program, it was GetQueuedCompletionStatus() that handled the error.

Which is a generic helper function that handles IOCP for any device driver.  There is no context, the OVERLAPPED structure is not nearly enough to indicate how the I/O request got started.  Turn to [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113996), it documents the default mapping from NTSTATUS error codes to winapi error codes.  The mapping that GetQueuedCompletionStatus() uses. Relevant entries in the list are:

```
STATUS_NETWORK_NAME_DELETED          ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED
STATUS_LOCAL_DISCONNECT              ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED
STATUS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT             ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED
STATUS_ADDRESS_CLOSED                ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED
STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED       ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED
STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET              ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED
```

These were, ahem, not fantastic choices.  Probably goes back to very early Windows, back when Lanman was the network layer of choice.  WSAGetLastError() is pretty powerless to map ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED back to a WSA specific error, the NTSTATUS code was lost when GetQueuedCompletionStatus() set the "last error" code for the thread.  So it doesn't, it just returns what it can.

---

What you'd *expect* is a WSAGetQueuedCompletionStatus() function so this error translation can happen correctly, using Winsock rules.  There isn't one.  These days I prefer to use the ultimate authority on how to write Windows code properly, the .NET Framework source as available from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,22f73d005323d27a).  I linked to the source for SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionCallback() method.  Which contains the key:

```
// The Async IO completed with a failure.
// here we need to call WSAGetOverlappedResult() just so Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() will return the correct error.
bool success = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.WSAGetOverlappedResult(
    m_CurrentSocket.SafeHandle,
    m_PtrNativeOverlapped,
    out numBytes,
    false,
    out socketFlags);
socketError = (SocketError)Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

Or in other words, you have to make an *extra* call to WSAGetOverlappedResult() to get the proper return value from GetLastError().  This is not very intuitive :)